# SCCM: Check if Truecrypt is Enabled

Tags: powershell, encryption, sccm, truecrypt

My company uses Truecrypt (I know) to encrypt all their Windows 7 workstations. It's installed by default into the image, but it's run manually to encrypt the drive. I need to figure out a way to query all of our workstations to figure out whether or not the workstation has actually been encrypted with Truecrypt.

I'm not actually sure how to do this. As far as I'm aware, Truecrypt doesn't set any registry flags or something I can query from the WMI. About the only way I can think to do this is to figure out how to query the size on disk and see if it's easily divisible by 512... but I haven't actually been able to find or build a script that properly reports the same size on disk that's reported in explorer, even when calling kernal32!GetCompressedFileSizeW

Anyone have any ideas where to look? I'm honestly a bit at a loss.

Comment: Ask on superuser or serverfault. This site is for programming questions.

Comment: Question would be better placed on [sf], profession level administration is covered there - SCCM meets that criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this one out, I was approaching it from the wrong direction.

[Encrypted Disk Detector](https://www.magnetforensics.com/free-tool-encrypted-disk-detector/) did this for me.

I just created a batch file with the following command:

```
start /B /wait edd.exe /accepteula /batch > \\server\share\%computername%_eddresults.txt
```